# How to apply a free bootstrap theme template on sharepoint web page?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, themes, intranet

I want to change the theme of sharepoint web page (intranet webpage) using bootstrap ready theme templates, how?

I want to apply a nice colors theme and reorder the content to be tidy.

I am using sharepoint2013.

Can any one help me step by step, because I am new in designing web pages.

Comment: This is too broad and complex of a question for StackOverflow (we specialize in solving **specific** problems). If you want this done, you should hire a web developer and pay him/her money to change the website.

Comment: Check out : https://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/